# dot image in the background is not visible

Tags: css

I have 2 issues with my page.

1. I have dots as background in my wrapper div. Its not visible in both fF and chrome.
2. I have css background gradients for navigation. It looks fine in Chrome, but not in FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the background image to the dots but after that you set the gradient in the background. It overwrites the dots, maybe you could use multiple backgrounds.
Check [this link](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/multiple-bg-css-gradients) for more about that (and the gradient declaration)

Answer (score 0):

You should post the relevant sections of your CSS.

FF and WebKit have different formats for gradients.  I believe that CSS3 is closer to the FF style, so you'll have to provide multiple alternative CSS statements.  However, on Chrome 10 and FF4, your page looks identical.

As for the dots, is it set on the same div as the gradient?  A gradient is an "image".  You may need to either use two different overlaying div's and then change the opacity of the top div, or specify multiple images for the background, but change the order of your layering of the background images.

Comment: So what would be the alternative css statements?

Comment: You'll have to use multiple background images, specified in order such that the "dots" overlay the gradient.  However, your "dots" PNG must be transparent to show the gradient.  Also, multiple background images are *not* supported by all browsers (at least not in IE), and many old versions of modern browsers don't support them.  So use them only if you are targeting users that have the newest browsers.  Otherwise, you'll have to use two div's.